# lumen laravel: How to return the message of the first error?

Tags: laravel, lumen

I need to customize the validation response in Lumen as follow

```
{
    "result": null,
    "count": 0,
    "statusCode": -1,
    "statusMessage": "...."
}
```

As you see, Only one status message must be shown, no matter how many errors occurred. To do so, I added the following function in base controller

```
protected function buildFailedValidationResponse(Request $request, array $errors)
{
    $string = null;

    foreach ($errors as $error)
    {
        $string = $error[0];
        break;
    }

    return [
        "result" => null,
        "count" => 0,
        "statusCode" => -1,
        "statusMessage" => $string
    ];
}
```

This is the result of `dd($errors)`

```
array:2 [
    "user_id" => array:1 [
        0 => "The user id field is required."
    ]
    "asd" => array:1 [
        0 => "The asd field is required."
    ]
]
```

It works but it seems messy! How can I return the message of the first error?

Comment: try $errors[0][0]

Comment: $erros['user_id'] exists but $errors[0] not found

Comment: the errors object has its own `$errors->first()` since its a collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take advantage of Collections. If `$errors` are already a collection (surely an `ErrorBag`), you can have it as array errors and then [flatten](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-flatten) them.

```php
$errors = collect($errors);

$string = $errors->flatten()->first();
```

Answer (score 1):

if your array is like this:

```
$array = [
    "user_id"=> [
        0 => "sssss"
    ],
    "asd"=> [
        0 => "ttttt"
    ]
];
```

this will help you :

```
return reset($array)[0];
```

result: `sssss`